# setBackgroundColor(int color) and RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, background-color

When i used this XML file...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF0000"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

..I see that background color wrap content

http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/8225/rlayout.jpg

But if i write this RelativeLayout by code...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("Hello world");

    //Añado texto
    layout.addView(text);

    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    setContentView(layout); 
}
```

...I see that background color match parent instead of wrap content

http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/1427/rlayoutfull.jpg

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are never setting the layout params:

```
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and I think that you should place the:

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText("Hello world");
```

and all other view you will add to your layout before you setting the layout params, otherwise there will be no content to wrap-around.

Edit:

what happens when you set:

```
tried to replace between the two:

 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

?

Comment: I get the same result... i don't understand why....because i think my code and XML file is identical =S

Comment: I forgot "layout.setLayoutParams" ! Now i tried to add textview to RelativeLayout and then add params to relativelayout but i get the same result :S

Comment: The same, All screen is red. I think that haven't any effect because i tried to use 300px width and height and i also see all screen red :S

Comment: If i use a LinearLayout and then i add the relativelayout (with its params and textview) to the linearlayout, it works perfectly like the XML file. Do you understand why?

Comment: I guess that if your relative layout is your root view then the layout params are treated differently.

Comment: maybe...i have been reading android.view, android.app.activity, etc... and i have seen that root view in a XML has like parent view a framelayout created by android.policy.PhoneWindow. Thanks very much for all!